# I want a function in C on linux to collect core dump without terminating the process

Tags: c, linux, coredump

abort() do collect the core dump, but I don't want the process to terminate. dump_core() collects the core dump, but in kernel space. Is there any function equivalent to dump_core() in user space?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do it yourself is to `fork` the process (which creates a complete copy of the parent process) and call `abort` from the child process.

The child process will be aborted with a core-dump, while the parent process continues as if nothing happened.

Comment: This works well if the requirement is to only capture the core for the active thread from which `fork()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`gcore`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html).

```
    .
    .
    .
char command[ 1024 ];
sprintf( command, "gcore -o /core/file/name %d", getpid() );
system( command );
    .
    .
    .
```

Error and bounds checking are omitted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such Linux C command. However, you may find some third party tools that can do this for you. For example, [Google coredumper](https://sourceforge.net/projects/goog-coredumper/), which is also supposed to be able to capture all the threads. Another way would be to attach `gdb` to your running process, and issue the `gcore` command. This is essentially what the [gcore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcore.1.html) command line utility does.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel generates SIGSEGV signal to the process whenever coredumps, I think you should attach a handler to the SIGSEGV signal([Link](http://www.alexonlinux.com/how-to-handle-sigsegv-but-also-generate-core-dump)) and call fork from that handler function.